# React Native image performance

Tags: react-native, expo

In my React Native app I use image resources in the bundle for some of the UI elements. On some of the screens, I download images from the web for FlatList Items. When I switch to a UI that is image heavy, the images that I use for the UI elements loaded from the bundle show almost after all the images in the FlatList loads which seems very unprofessional for a native app.
I searched the web for performant image loaders, found some but since I use Expo for development, I can't use native plugins.
Can someone direct me to useful resources to overcome this problem?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Also If I have a FlatList with 10 items of which are only 2 concurrently visible, all 10 items are loaded at once...